# Quality loss using ImageIO.write

Tags: image, scala, jpeg, bufferedimage

I have noticied significant quality loss using ImageIO.write, how I can disable automatic compression ?

```
val baos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream
val newBi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth, img.getHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
val gr = newBi.createGraphics()
gr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Color.WHITE, null)
ImageIO.write(newBi, "jpeg", baos)
val b = baos.toByteArray
baos.close()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [ImageWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriteParam.html#setCompressionQuality%28float%29).

```
ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT); // Needed see javadoc
param.setCompressionQuality(1.0F); // Highest quality
writer.write(image);
```

For non-photo images use .png.

---

As @PiotrekDe commented, the following seems more logical.

```
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param)
```

Comment: I have tried those methods but for some reasons the output image is filled with black. Do you know where it could be coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, I knew of these methods (and that png is slow), but in general I pick png.

Comment: I think you need to pass `param` back to `writer`, like: `writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param)`

Answer (score 2):

JPEG Cmpression is lossy. But PNG compression is lossless. So, i suggest to write in png format. That means you won't loss quality even if you compress in PNG format. Simple lines:

```
ImageIO.write(newBI,"png",someOutputStream);
```

But, if you want it in jpg format with quality, set Quality to 100%. The following code may help you.

```
    ImageWriter jpgWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg").next();
    ImageWriteParam jpgWriteParam = jpgWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    jpgWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(1f);
    jpgWriter.setOutput(someOutputStream);
     //better to use ImageOutputStream
    jpgWriter.write(null,new IIOImage(yourImage, null, null), jpgWriteParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

jpeg images are using lossy compression.
Use png instead. That's compressed too but with a lossless algorithm.