# Is there an easy to use Image library for simple operations (read,write,rotate,re-size)?

Tags: java, image, image-processing

My use case is pretty simple which I think is shared with many other developers.

I would like to:

```
 1. Load an image
 2. Read EXIF Orientation details (If available)
 3. Rotate (90, 180, 270) degrees
 4. Resize and store images.
```

I tried going through the forums and then tried:

Sanselan: Reads `EXIF`, but not `JPG` images. Also, `commons-imaging` download links are all broken.

`Java ImageIO/Graphics2D`: Can rotate/re-size(not one liner, but is understandable) although as **suggested you do lose quality when rotating**.

*BUT does not read all `JPG` images (Throws `CMMException` for some `jpg` file)

The rest are either too old and not maintained anymore, have no documentation at all or I missed the 'good' one.

Can anyone suggest a library that supports these few 'simple' use cases?

*Using `Sanselan` to read `EXIF` is fine. **`Read/Rotate/Re-size (JPGs)` is my main problem**

Comment: AFAIK, JPG is not lossless format, every time you save it, you loose something.

Comment: @user1516873 Does this mean that when a camera takes (JPG) picture in landscape orientation the only way to view the image is to tilt the camera?

Comment: no, loss in quality happens only when you read JPG image in some internal format (not important, what) and save it again. Your camera not rewrite image every time, so it is safe to rotate it as you want ;)

Comment: Interesting read regarding the Orientation/rotate of JPGs: http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/lossless-rotation.html

Answer (score 4):

[Thumbnailator](https://github.com/coobird/thumbnailator) is a simple Java library which has no external dependencies which can (a) load an image, (b) read the Exif metadata and automatically rotate the image, (c) resize and (d) store the image in one single statement:

```
Thumbnails.of("path/to/image")
    .size(320, 240)
    .toFile("path/to/thumbnail");
```

The above will:

- open the image
- resize it so that it will fit in a 320 pixel x 240 pixel region, while
- maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image, and
- properly orient the image according to the Exif metadata, and
- store it to a new image

If one desires to perform additional rotations, a `rotate` method is also available.

*Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of Thumbnailator.*

Comment: Seems exactly what I am looking for and I can see it is on maven as well. I will try it and mark as answer. Note that I expect it to break as well if it uses out-of-the-box ImageIO.read(file) to read a JPG

Comment: Didn´t know about it. Sounds cool !

Comment: @johnd Thumbnailator does use the Image I/O API to read JPEGs, but it doesn't use `ImageIO.read` as is -- it performs additional actions to retrieve the Exif metadata (which _can_ be done with extra work!) from the JPEG along with the image.

Comment: @coobird I tried Thumbnailator with the bad image and it breaks as well :( It is very easy to use though as needed quite a lot of code to do the same. Can you explain how do you process the EXIF data in terms of IO operations? Currently I use Sanselan, which means that I need to a. Read EXIF, rotate and write to file with ImageIO/Graphics2D and the write/copy updated EXIF. This is very heavy on IO. Does your library do the same on 1 IO write? i.e. Read Image, process and write (with updated EXIF) in one file operation?

Comment: @johnd Thumbnailator does do the Exif read and image read operation in a single file opening operation. (It uses Image I/O as the backend, so it's probably not a single read, but probably doesn't do anything too inefficient.) One thing Thumbnailator does not do is to modify the Exif and write it into the thumbnail image.

Comment: @coobird can you tell me please,if Thumbnailator can JUST read exif data?(w/o resize and rotate). Interesting if i can extract value of exif data(orientation).

Answer (score 2):

Might be much of an overkill if this is the only thing you will have to do, but **[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/)** is an excellent image processing library.
It comes with [Java bindings](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html), and is under BSD licence.

I say this is an overkill for a simple use case like that, simply because it can do [so much more](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/index.html#). It is always my first weapon of choice for years though, simply because it has bindings with lots of languages, is portable pretty much everywhere and even now has GPU support :).

There are already SO questions that answer exactly what you want I think. Look **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259678/easiest-way-to-transpose-an-image-rotate-by-90-degrees-using-opencv)** for an example

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You just better use java 2D library itself.

Like :

```
paint(Graphics g)
Graphics g2= (Graphics)g
g2.draw();
g2.rotate(give parameters)
```

Comment: I am using Graphics2D (in one of my implementations) to rotate the image. As many posts suggests, even by reading the JPG file (ImageIO) you lose quality.

Comment: @johnd a suggestion for you, it woudld be better if you mention all these kind of details that why you won't use `Graphics2D` and all in the question... you will get more good answers....:) by the way have you tried `ImageReader` instead of `ImageIO`?. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015197/quality-loss-using-imageio-write

Comment: @pinkpanther I thought this was implied by saying that I use ImageIO and that it loses on quality. I will update my question ;) I haven't tried ImageReader because I assumed that since it is part of ImageIO package, it will use the same code. Am I missing somthing?

Comment: @johnd in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015197/quality-loss-using-imageio-write), using `ImageWriter` instead of `ImageIO` solved the problem, that's the reason I suggested...:) I don't know anything else...

Comment: Yes, with ImageWriter one can set a high quality 1.0F.