# Pixel values getting changed in jpg image

Tags: java, jpeg

When I tried to write a `jpg` image I observed that some `pixel` values gets changed

```
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File(dPath));
```

1.Is there a way to set quality to `100%` when writing.
2.Why does the `pixel` value changes. Is it because when trying to write it compress the data and then stores.
3.What is the file extension for jpeg 2000 image and does `ImageIO.write` allow us to write a jpeg 2000 image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is not lossless even when at 100%, you may want to use PNG or JPEG2000.
2. This is due to the compression. Even at 100% it's just the least possible loss.
3. jp2, although there might not be a compatible format in the JVM to handle this.

---

I would recommend usage of just a PNG if you want a lossless image type.

To see how to set JPG write quality to 100%, you can go see [Quality loss using ImageIO.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015197/quality-loss-using-imageio-write)