# Reading and Writing an image using BufferedImage

Tags: java, rgb, pixel, bufferedimage

The sample code is below. The code works perfect and creates an image accurately. But the created image (when reading back, and taking the pixels in), the pixels seem to be 1 or 2 values off. 
I am doing simple testing by printing the pixels as they are read in, and before they are saved back to file. I then run another tester on the new image and the printed pixels are, as I said 1 or 2 values off (in pixels, such as '24', to '25'). 
But most pixels are accurately, just a few are not. Is it something to do with how the image is written back?

```
try
{
    //Read in image 
    BufferedImage  imgBuf = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));

    //take in pixels etc., and simply do nothing with them - testing puposes

    //Write back the image
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imagePixelArray[0].length, imagePixelArray.length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", new File("new-image.jpg"));
}
catch(IOException i){};
```

**EDIT**

Below is the code of how the pixels are split into arrays, and then re-assigned back into an array using bit shifting. Again, don't worry about the logic of the program. I need to make sure that these these pixels (represented as redPixels, greenPixels and bluePixels) are the same when reading back the new created image. The code below uses the code above using BufferedImage. I did use GIF files. But I know that there is someway of properly encoding JPEGs (rather than compressing the data)

```
    int i=0;
      //Loop through RGBarray[] assigning their respecctive colour components using bit shifting
      //jpegPixels[255][255][3] - the third part of the array is their colour comonents
      //0 - red
      //1 - green
      //2 - blue
      for(int row=0; row<h; row++)
      {
         for(int col=0; col<w; col++)
         {
            jpegPixels[row][col][0] = ((RGBarray[i]>>16)&0xff);
            jpegPixels[row][col][1] = ((RGBarray[i]>>8)&0xff);
            jpegPixels[row][col][2] = (RGBarray[i]&0xff);
            i++;
         }
      }

//3 arrays - redPixels, greenPixels and bluePixels are assigned from jpegPixels[][][]

//loop again returning back the pixel information using bit shifting
for(int row=0; row<reconstructedJPEG.length; row++)
      {
         for(int col=0; col<reconstructedJPEG[0].length; col++)
         {
            int rgb = (redPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 16 | (greenPixels[row][col] & 0xff) << 8 | (bluePixels[row][col] & 0xff);

            bufferedImage.setRGB(col, row, rgb);
         }
      }
```

Comment: `catch(IOException i){};` -- seriously? Regarding your question, JPG uses lossy compression. Pixels are never exact with this type of file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "1 or 2 values off"? It sounds like something is adding 1 to the value of a certain pixel, but are you reading the compressed or uncompressed data?

Comment: whats wrong? Is i said this is just a sample code to illustrate what my problem is. Thats not the issue of the question

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: no but it is just code that should never occur. But please look at the rest of my comment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels nailed it, I think. Recompressing may change a few pixels. I would need to look at the spec, but if the image displays correctly, it's probably the compression type. Try using an uncompressed file format like DIB or BMP and a lossless format to make sure that it's not changing pixel values. It shouldn't be.

Comment: No I am not doing any compression to the pixels at all. For testing purposes I am just reading the pixels in, and writing them back out against using BufferedImage. As in, the pixel values itself are being altered slightly by 1 or 2 values. I don't know wyhy. From testing and testing, it now seems to do with writing the values back to file ?

Comment: If you're looking at pixel data, they're being uncompressed and if you're writing them out as a JPEG file, they're being recompressed. You can't examine pixel data in a JPEG without uncompressing, by definition. If you mean something is changing the compressed bytes,then you have a bigger problem as it won't uncompress.

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: see edit to answer please.

Comment: OK I see.. But that doesn't explain why only some pixels are unchanged, but there odd ones, are being altered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPG uses lossy compression, and thus pixels are never exact with this type of file format. If you look at JPG files that have been copied several times, you'll start seeing an accumulation of errors, often at the borders and edges within the image. If you want perfect storage of pixels, use a different image file format type that uses either no compression or lossless compression such as PNG.

---

As an aside, code like this:

```
catch(IOException i){};
```

Should never be present, even in "just a sample code to illustrate ...".

---

**Edit**
You state:

> No I am not doing any compression to the pixels at all. For testing purposes I am just reading the pixels in, and writing them back out against using BufferedImage. As in, the pixel values itself are being altered slightly by 1 or 2 values. I don't know wyhy. From testing and testing, it now seems to do with writing the values back to file ?

You're using JPG -- and so again, you are compressing whether you know it or not.

Again, have you tried your experiment with PNG formatted images?

---

**Edit 2**
You state:

> But that doesn't explain why only some pixels are unchanged, but there odd ones, are being altered.

The amount of altering and the number of pixels potentially altered will depend on the compression level (inverse of the quality level) used by the ImageWriter. This can be set if you extract out the actual ImageWriter used for jpg images. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015197/quality-loss-using-imageio-write) for instance.

Comment: OK I see.. But that doesn't explain why only some pixels are unchanged, but there odd ones, are being altered.

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: Please see **Edit 2**.

Comment: Thanks again. My program is actually using JPEG operation, such as DCT transformation and compression, then the inverse to return back to pixel form again. I know that the intial pixel set will be different after compression etc., but I am only taking into account on the inverse (returned pixels) and the pixels from the created image (should be same). So even though I am compressing the data, the method BufferedImage.Write() compresses the file again? So in relation your last edit, the ImageWriteParam class is the class I would need to consider using to control the compression back on to file?

Comment: Man, every thread that I've seen @HovercraftFullOfEels respond to, he does a lot of work. I hope Douglas Grealis appreciates this answer and accepts this as the right answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer as the right answer because he did provided me a lot of detail. On the other hand, I did use a different image format, which was GIF files. They don't use lossy compession, and I did the same testing and I'm still getting inaccurate results. In fact they are more worse than using a JPEG. So I definitely don't think its a compression issue. It has something to do with writing the image back !

Comment: @DouglasGrealis: `"...I'm still getting inaccurate results"` -- hm curious. Then please don't accept my answer then since it is incorrect. But do consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please check the link) if one can be created, so that we can test the issue for ourselves and thereby hopefully come up with a better and correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check my edit. I hope this is clear on what my problem is.