# ImageWriteParam set compression quality not working

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to create an app that combines several JPG into one big JPG without any compression. But in my test sample, when I combine 8 images (800KB), the output is only 280KB.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015197/quality-loss-using-imageio-write) as reference in writing the code. But no matter what value I inserted to param.setCompressionQuality(...), the output is always 280KB and doesn't change.

```
String name = dir.getName();
System.out.println("Combining images... #" + name);
BufferedImage result = combine(dir);

ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(1.0F); // set highest quality
try {
    File outputFile = new File(outputFolder + "\\" + name + ".JPG");
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFile);
    writer.setOutput(ios);
    writer.write(result);   
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

dir is a File type variable indicating my source folder location.
combine() is a method that returns BufferedImage.

Comment: Note that "JPG without any compression" is kind of a contradiction in terms. JPEG is always compressed. But I think I get what you are after, see answer below... :-)

Comment: @haraldK I think I chose the wrong words... Perhaps "JPG with less compression" would have sounded better. Although, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work, is because you need to pass the `ImageWriteParam` (`param` in your code) to the `write` method to have an effect.

The `getDefaultWriteParam()` method will only create it for you, it will not stay "attached" to the `writer`. See the [`ImageWriter.write` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageWriter.html#write(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata,%20javax.imageio.IIOImage,%20javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam)) for further information.

The code will then look like this:

```
BufferedImage result = ...

ImageWriter writer = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg").next();
ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

...

writer.setOutput(...);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(result, null, null), param); // nulls are metadata and thumbnails, don't worry :-)
```

Comment: You are truly a godsend! The codes are now working properly. Thank you very much for your help :)